# Some weird info in chrome console

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am using a business computer for web debugging and I found some weird message(which I did not define in my HTML code) appeared in console once I loaded any web pages. For example, I got **"Got main parameters"** from **content.ts**, **"Reporting WPM load to agent"** from **wpm.ts**. When I checked the chrome extensions I found only Symantec and Aternity extensions were ativated. I wonder if those two extensions generated those wried messages.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from a peek around their docs that ["WPM" is Aternity's "Web Page Monitoring" tool](https://help.aternity.com/bundle/console_admin_guide_12_1_server_local/page/console/topics/console_admin_app_web_config.html).  My hunch is that the same is true of the "Got main parameters" message-- you might see if you can trace it from the chrome console to determine its source.